# what happened to the timestamp field in DNS console?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2

I just installed DNS server on a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine. When I look at the records in the console, I have Name, Type, Data fields, but no Timestamp field. What's up with that? How do I get it? I can't tell if records are timestamped or static.
Edit: every other zone and even sub-domains within this zone show the timestamp field. Also, if I look at this zone on this machine using another server (also 2012 R2), I also see the timestamp. Just in this zone on this machine, when I click on the zone, the Timestamp field disappears. It seems to be headbashingly nonsensical bug #34383743736. Thanks, Microsoft!

Comment: View... Add/Remove Columns... Timestamp?

Comment: Nope. It's not in the list of available columns.